$\text{Res}\circ \text{Cores}$ in the context of group cohomology
Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ be a finite index($=n$) subgroup . Let $A$ be a $G$ module.
Let $H^1(G,A)$ denote group Galois cohomology.
Restriction map $\text{Res}: H^1(G,A)\to H^1(H,A)$ is defined by restricting the domain of a cocycle from $G$ to $H$.
On the other hand, there is a what we call corestriciton map $\text{Cores}: H^1(H,A)\to H^1(G,A)$.
It is known that $\text{Cores}\circ \text{Res}=[n]$ where $[n]$ is $n$-th multiple map.But what is know about $\text{Res}\circ \text{Cores}$ ?
Is it true that $\text{Res}\circ \text{Cores}=\text{Image of Trace}:  H^1(H,A)\to H^1(H,A), P\mapsto \Sigma_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma P$ ?
Related but without information on trace: Why $\mathrm{Restriction}\circ \mathrm{Corestriction}$ is multiplication on cohomology?

@FShrike Thank you for your reaction. I have seen the link, but there is no information about my question regarding whether it is trace or not.

I think they show it's also just $[n]$, no? So that tells you all you need

@FShrike Please look at the last comment by Hunter. It is not true that $\text{Res} \circ \text{Cores} = [n]$, and they don't mention whether the true formula is given by trace or not.

Oh I see, Dummit and Foote were in error. Shame

I think what you want follows from Wuthrich's formula here when $H$ is normal. When $H$ is not normal, this argument fails (and I'm not sure what the formula means in that case either, so maybe it's ok) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284445/is-there-an-explicit-description-of-the-corestriction-map-h1h-m-rightarrow
